# Powershell still prompting for credential even when using System.Management.Automation.PSCredential

Tags: powershell, line-continuation

I have created the following variable `$cred`:

```
$User = "sa"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "teste" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
```

Then, I open a connection with dbatools script.

```
$server1 = Connect-DbaInstance `
-SqlInstance '192.168.0.61\TESTE2017' `
-SqlCredential $cred`
-TrustServerCertificate;
```

But powershell still prompt asking for a credential:

[image]

Why?

Comment: I cant’t test to confirm right now, but think you need a space between the ```-SqlCredential  $cred``` and the back-tick, otherwise Powershell treats it as part of the parameter value rather than as a line continuation character.

Comment: @mclayton evidently. One of many good reason why not to use backticks for line continuations and use splatting instead

Comment: @mclayton I can't believe it was just that, thank you.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon- even more confusing is a trailing space *after* a backtick, especially if the IDE doesn’t show a visual indicator (I use notepad a lot). Having said that, I tend to prefer line continuations as opposed to splatting - just the way I grew up I guess :-).

Comment: You included a space on each line before the backtick, why'd you omit it on that line? The dead give away was the entire trustservercertificate parameter being in the credential username field.

Answer (score 1):

There's great information in the comments; let me try to summarize:

**PowerShell commands (pipelines) *situationally* require *explicit* line continuation using a *line-ending* `` ` ``** (the so-called backtick, which is PowerShell's [general escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)), notably **when spreading *distinct arguments* across multiple lines**.

- By contrast, **`` ` `` is *not* needed if a command's line is *syntactically incomplete***, because PowerShell then *automatically* looks for the command's completion on the next line; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Example 1
  Get-ChildItem -File | # NO ` needed: | implies that the command continues
    Sort-Object Length -Descending

  # Example 2
  1..3 | ForEach-Object { # NO ` needed: { implies that the command continues
    1 + $_
  }

  # Example 3
  (Get-Date). # NO ` needed: . implies that the command continues
    Year
  ```

**If and when you *do* need `` ` `` for line-continuation, the following *strict rules* apply:**

- The **line-ending `` ` `` must NOT be followed by *any* additional characters** - not even *whitespace*.
- The **line-ending `` ` `` must NOT be *directly attached* to the last argument** to the line - **make sure that it is preceded by a space**.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - If you do accidentally directly attach `` ` `` to a (syntactically incomplete) last argument, *it* is (potentially) continued on the next line, including the newline, IF that newline starts with a non-whitespace character.
  - In your case, this meant that *verbatim* `-TrustServerCertificate` was appended to the *stringified* value of variable `$cred`, which resulted in a *string* value such as the following (`$cred` - uselessly - stringified to its *type name*):

    ```bash
    System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
    --TrustServerCertificate
    ```

    - It is this string value that became the argument to the `-SqlCredential` parameter, resulting in the symptom you saw.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, a space is *not* needed if the preceding argument is itself *syntactically complete*, but not only is it safe to *always* use a space, it also provides visual clarity.</sup>